# Changes in file in "local" structure don't work

Tags: php, magento, local

When I create a file in the "local" structure like on file structure in "core", Magento doesn't see that changes.
Why? Maybe I need to change some other file?
I changed `core/Mage/Cutomer/controllers/AcountController.php`,
put that changed file in `local/Mage/Cutomer/controllers/AcountController.php`,
but got no effect.

Magento works with "core" files.

Comment: blocks,helper,Model everything else will work in local but controllers won't, you have to rewrite controllers in a new module and update the desired function.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that creating a custom module is the better way to do this, because you can use the 'ModuleName' as a description to indicate what changes this module will do to core and make it much easier for other developer to modify your code in the future

app/code/local/MageIgniter/ModuleName/controllers/AcountController.php

```
<?php
   require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';
   class MageIgniter_ModuleName_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{

   }
```

app/code/local/MageIgniter/ModuleName/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
  <MageIgniter_ModuleName>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
  </MageIgniter_ModuleName>
</modules>
<frontend>
  <routers>
    <customer>
      <args>
        <modules>
          <MageIgniter_ModuleName before="Mage_Customer">MageIgniter_ModuleName</MageIgniter_ModuleName>
        </modules>
      </args>
    </customer>
  </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

/app/etc/modules/MageIgniter_ModuleName.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageIgniter_ModuleName>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MageIgniter_ModuleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Read more @

[How to extend Magento core controller?](http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/)

[Magento: Overriding Core Files (Blocks, Models, Resources, Controllers)](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/)

Answer (score -1):

Create your own module and write an observer that hooks into the magento logic.

Answer (score -1):

I think magento is taking code pool as "core". 
So it start finding that class in core direct.

so you can change file
app -> etc -> modules -> Mage_All.xml
find following and change codepool like, change to

```
   <Mage_Customer>
         <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Eav/>
            <Mage_Dataflow/>
            <Mage_Directory/>
        </depends>
    </Mage_Customer>
```

Comment: Don't think that this is the right way, changing core functionality.

Comment: I found same question as this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916609/local-vs-core-contoller